# Target of URI doesn't exist

Tags: dart, uri

In the Visual Studio program, after installing and downloading the Dart package, I created the first project, but I got the following error message:

**Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:dart_application_1/dart_application_1.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist**

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line

[image]

After Import dart file.

[image]

Cool Like This.... Thanks You. Happy to Help you.

[image]